# How to get the number of records in a directory that has .tsv extension

Tags: linux

How to get the number of records in a directory that has .tsv extension. There are 100 .tsv files, I would like to see the file names and number of records in each file to be output in another file.

```
abc.tsv 200
pqr.tsv 300
```

Comment: You mean "number of *files* in a directory"? Is each line of a tsv file a "record"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming records are one line each, you just need `wc`:

```
$ wc -l *.tsv
 5 bar.tsv
 5 foo.tsv
10 total
```

Or, if you want just non-empty lines, `grep` for any character:

```
$ grep -c . *.tsv
bar.tsv:4
foo.tsv:4
```

Or, remove the "total" line from the `wc` output with `sed` and redirect to a file:

```
$ wc -l *.tsv | seq '$d' > counts.txt
```

Comment: But would like to save them in a file. say, counts.txt

Comment: @UnixPhile, [Redirections](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Redirection) are your friend here (and something that's useful get to know). Also [pipes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput#Pipes). I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

The following example is for .html files in one of my folders:

```
$ wc -l *.html
   1479 bookmarks.home.html
    908 bookmarks.html
   1459 bookmarks.office.html
   3846 total
```

Just replace .html with .tsv